# Simple Calculator calculates wrong

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Earlier I asked about the same topic, a simple calculator, but the thread now is kind of cluttered and isn't up-to-date any more. I hope gets annoyed by this, but I find a new thread kind of useful.

I got an JavaScript exercise to do, which is to script a calculator, which has almost the same functionality than the built-in Windows (7) one. This means that you have one field to enter some values, and a small one above which displays the previously entered value plus the calculating operation.

A user sent me some code for my needs which I liked because of it's simplicity and I tried to adapt it.

I currently am working to get only one operation to work, but later there will be the other three main operations, square root, etc..

Everything works just fine by now, only the, which is kind of disturbing, calculating itself does not. For example: If you enter 5 + 5 (or any other number), then click on equals, nothing happens. If you then again enter any number (click on plus before) and then hit equals it gives you an completely random result, or the result of your previous calculation.

This is what I got:

```
var number = 0;                    //the result
var operation = ' ';               //the chosen calculating operation
var temp_Val = 0;                  //the last entered value (for the subdisplay)

var print_equal = function () {
    var displayVal = document.getElementById("display");        
    displayVal.value = number;                                  
};

var num_add = function () {
    var displayVal = document.getElementById("display");        
    temp_Val = displayVal.value;    //saves the value of the display (for the subdisplay)
    console.log(temp_Val);      //schreibt den Wert des Displays auf die Konsole
    number += parseFloat(displayVal.value);  //calculates the result
    operation = '+';             //saves the used operation (for the subdisplay)
    print_subdisplay();          //runs the function that's building the value of the subdisplay
    displayVal.value = "";               //resets the main display
};

var print_subdisplay = function () {
    var subdisplayVal = document.getElementById("subdisplay");
    subdisplayVal.value = temp_Val + operation;    //creates a String with both the first entered value and the operation
};
```

HTML:

```
<!-- Displays -->
        <input type="text" name="display" id="display" value="0" class="display">
        <input type="text" name="subdisplay" id="subdisplay" class="subdisplay" readonly>

<!-- Calculating operations -->
        <input type="button" onclick="print_equal()" id="equal" value="=">
        <input type="button" onclick="num_add()" id="plus" value="+">

<!-- Reset -->
        <input type="button" value="C" onClick="reset()" class="reset">
```

Here's the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hJfFd/1/

I would find it incredibly nice if you could help me, since I'm sitting here trying to get this to work since nearly 4 hours (incl. researching). Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you might be confused in what your logic for each button should do.  The `=` button should add whatever is in the left box to whatever is in the right box.  Your current code only performs this addition when pressing the `+` button.

Comment: You're right, but I don't want the right textfield to be enter-able. Every user-entry should be done in the left/first field.

Comment: Since it was bothering me I added a function to automatically return focus to the input field after you clicked an operator. I hope you enjoy :)

http://jsfiddle.net/CpvqR/22/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution that should help you get started implementing the rest of the calculator.  I would recommend going through and adding your comments again.  And understand what each line of code does.  A good way to do that would be if you are confused about a line of code take it out then play around with the calculator and you may see why that line of code was added etc..  Good luck!

```
var number = 0;                                                 //the result
var operation = ' ';                                            //the chosen calculating operation
var temp_Val = 0;                                               //the last entered value (for the subdisplay)

var print_equal = function () {
  var displayVal = document.getElementById("display");
  var subdisplayVal = document.getElementById("subdisplay");
  if(subdisplayVal.value == '')
    return false;
  temp_Val = displayVal.value;
  if(temp_Val == '')
    temp_Val = 0;
  if(operation == '+')
    number += parseFloat(temp_Val);
  subdisplayVal.value = ""; 
  displayVal.value = number;
  temp_Val = 0;
  number = 0;
  operation = ' ';
};

var num_add = function () {
  var displayVal = document.getElementById("display");      
  temp_Val = displayVal.value;
  if(temp_Val == '')
    return false;
  if(operation == '+')
    number += parseFloat(displayVal.value);
  else
    number = parseFloat(displayVal.value);                      
  operation = '+';                                          
  print_subdisplay();                                           
  displayVal.value = "";                                        
};

var print_subdisplay = function () {
  var subdisplayVal = document.getElementById("subdisplay");
  subdisplayVal.value = number + operation;
};

function reset() {
  number = 0;
  operation = ' ';
  var displayVal = document.getElementById("display");
  displayVal.value = "0";
  var subdisplayVal = document.getElementById("subdisplay");
  subdisplayVal.value = ""; 
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CpvqR/21/

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but this doesn't solve the calculating part, I guess.

Comment: Oh okay I know what your having trouble with.  Give me a moment.

Comment: Added one more snippet.

Comment: Make sure to take a look at the latest fiddle and update.  I keep modifying it.  So it does not keep track of all the operations until you hit "=" like on the windows 7 calculator.  But hopefully this code will get you started.. If you want to implement it like the windows 7 calculator and are still having trouble post another fiddle here and i'll take a look at it over the weekend.

Answer (score 0):

There's a logic error in the code. If you follow this sequence of steps, it will work as expected:

1) enter 5

2) Click +

3) enter 5

3) Click + again

4) Click =

At this point 10 will appear in the "output" box. So your print_equal() function needs to somehow perform the final calculation BEFORE it prints the result to the screen, as the last operation (in this case the + operation) is not being performed.

Answer (score 0):

There are two simple problems with your current implementation.

1) You need to make sure to parse all of the input read from `displayVal`.  If you don't, you will be storing strings in variables that you think are integers (because JavaScript is loosely typed).  Replace the line in which you assign to `temp_Val` with

```
temp_Val = parseFloat(displayVal.value);
```

2) Your `=` button needs to do the actual math operation (or at least this is how most calculators work).  Replace the second line of your `print_equal` function with

```
displayVal.value = parseFloat(displayVal.value) + temp_Val;
```

Obviously, there are other things that you need to worry about (like using the correct operation), but this should at least get you going.

Comment: Thank you, I think this (and the other comments) got it working for me. Addition and Subtraction are working.

Answer (score 0):

Some day ago i wrote a very simple calc in js css3 and html5

example

http://jsfiddle.net/trjsJ/

js

```
function calc(e){
 var a=e.target.innerText,b=this.firstChild;
 b.value=a=='='?eval(b.value):a=='C'?'':b.value+a;
}
var gui=document.createElement('div');
gui.className='clc';
gui.innerHTML='<input><div>'+('789+456-123*C0./='.split('').join('</div><div>'))+'</div>';
gui.addEventListener('click',calc,false);

window.onload=function(){
 document.body.appendChild(gui);
}
```

css3

```
body,html{
 height:100%;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 background-color:#666;
}
*{
 box-sizing:border-box;
}
.clc{
 width:256px;
 height:320px;
 clear:both;
}
.clc>*{
 border:4px solid #666;
 border-radius:4px;
 font:normal normal bold 20px/56px Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
 border-radius:10px;
}
.clc>input{
 width:100%;
 height:20%;
 text-align:right;
 padding:0 20px;
}
.clc>div{
 width:25%;
 height:20%;
 background-color:#5a5a5a;
 color:#fff;
 text-align:center;
 float:left;
}
.clc>div:nth-child(4n+1){
 background-color:#f36573;
}
.clc>div:nth-last-child(1){
 width:100%;
 background-color:#ffb343;
}
```